# Up to which point (disk size) is Raid 6 safe to use?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, raid-10, raid6

I have been reading a lot of warnings about Raid-6 becoming less and less safe to use due to the storage amount per disk as well as array sizes increasing.

What are the best practice limits/when does it make sense to take the economical hit of using Raid-10 instead? (at which size)

We are considering these disk combinations:
Hotstorage:

- 10x4TB SSDs

Coldstorage:

- 10x10TB HDDs
- 15x10TB HDDs
- 12x12TB HDDs

Raid-6 would save us a lot of money, yet is it safe to use at those sizes in terms of normal failures and rebuild times.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-raid-6-stops-working-in-2019/

Comment: Most of your questions are heavily depended on your situation (budget, actual hardware, what happens on those disks and so on). For a general rundown as to why it might be undesirable check @CaldeiraG the question will probably be closed as being opinion based.

Comment: @CaldeiraG thanks, this article is quite old (2010) do the statements and math still hold true or did the error rate change

Comment: So I guess for SSDs a Raid-6 is pretty safe?